# Org-reveal not working with highlight.js

Tags: syntax-highlighting, org-reveal

Here is my `.org` file

```
   #+REVEAL_THEME: Moon
   #+REVEAL_PLUGINS: (highlight)
   
   #+begin_src html
    <h2 class="headline1> Hello </h2>
   #+end_src
```

The highlighting is not working . When i had a look at the `.html` file the css file (zenburn) from the highlight plugin was not loading. The path to the file was `lib/css/zenburn.css` while original path was inside `plugin/highlight/zenburn.css` . Think the reveal.js has changed its file structure . I tried to update `ox-reveal` but nothing worked . What am i doing wrong here .

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't work". Just what do you see, and what did you expect to see instead?

Comment: The source code was not being highlighted . Once i got the css correct in HTML file the highlighting worked correctly .

Comment: Put all such info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: @Drew i have mentioned in the question that "The highlighting is not working " . I went to the plugin folder and updated the path to css in `ox-reveal.el` and everything is working perfect though it will go back to the original in next update  :(